# How to bind button to Listbox item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**ViewModel**

```
  public class MainWindowViewModel:BindableBase
  {
     public IRelayCommand MyCommand { get; protected set; }


    private void CreateCommand()
    {

        this.MyCommand = new RelayCommand(MyCommandExecuted, CanExecuteMyCommand);
    }

    private void MyCommandExecuted(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Command Executed");
    }

    private bool CanExecuteMyCommand(object obj)
    {
        return true; // The value is based on Selected Item
    }
  }
```

**XAML**

```
     <ListBox
             x:Name="myListBox" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyClass}"
             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Path=HeaderName}" IsExpanded="True">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <DataGrid
                             x:Name="dataGrid"

                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RowVal}"  SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

<Button Content="Select" 

            Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand }" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListBox,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

**DataClass**

```
  public class DataClass 
   {
    public string HeaderName { get; set; }
    public object RowVal { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> ColumnCollection { get; set;}
    private object currentItem;

    public object CurrentItem
    {
        get
        {
            return currentItem;
        }
        set
        {
            currentItem = value;

        }
    }

}
```

How can I bind my button to Listbox item which is CurrentItem in DataClass ?

Comment: Is your Button element inside the ListBox element or are you simply not showing all of your code? Your question from yesterday talked about binding `SelectedItem`. What happened to that? If you bind the `SelectedItem` in your viewmodel, you'll have access to it when you use your button. Although, I might be misunderstanding your setup.. Could you show a short and complete example instead?

Comment: No the button element is not inside the Listbox control

Comment: @Default The current item is fired when I select the row but that is in DataClass and I want to bind it to `MyCommand` in my ViewModel.I dont have any idea how can I do it

Answer (score 1):

I created a complete example to show how I would do it. You would have to bind the parent element to `SelectedItem` as well, to keep track of when that item changes. Since the `SelectedItem` is public in your child class as well you can access that when your command triggers in your main view model.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParent}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Parent}">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChild}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Width="70" Content="Click me" Height="25" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

i.e. in `DoWork`, you can get the child from the parent via its public property.

```
public sealed class WindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Parent> parents;
    private readonly ICommand myCommand;
    private Parent selectedParent;

    public WindowViewModel()
    {
        parents = new ObservableCollection<Parent>
        {
            new Parent{ Name = "P1"},
            new Parent{ Name = "P2"}
        };
        myCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoWork);
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        var selectedChild = SelectedParent == null ? null : SelectedParent.SelectedChild;

    }

    public Parent SelectedParent
    {
        get { return selectedParent; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedParent == value)
                return;
            selectedParent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Parent> Parents
    {
        get { return parents; }
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get { return myCommand; }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

With the basic setup of Data models

```
public class Parent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Child> children;
    private Child m_SelectedChild;


    public Parent()
    {
        children = new ObservableCollection<Child>
        {
            new Child {Name = "C1"},
            new Child {Name = "C2"}
        };
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Child> Children
    {
        get { return children; }
    }

    public Child SelectedChild
    {
        get { return m_SelectedChild; }
        set
        {
            if (m_SelectedChild == value)
                return;
            m_SelectedChild = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

Another solution, if you are more interested of the Child item in your WindowViewModel is to change the relative source of where the binding should occur, in your DataGrid. i.e., the binding would look like this instead:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedChild, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" />
```

and then move the Property from `Parent` to `WindowViewModel`. With that you would be able to trigger changes to your button command when the child element changes for any of the Parent elements.

Comment: Well the code looks right but shouldnt the button get enabled when the item is clicked.Because its not happening here in your example ,It's invoking `m_SelectedChild` depended on its value we need to fire the CanExecuteMethod of the button .thats what I am missing

Comment: also `SelectedParent` is fired after double click can we make it to single click ? but i guess that would be another question

Comment: doubleclick on the list item? no, it only triggers on the single click. I thought you simply wanted to access the child item from your data template item in your viewmodel. a `CanExecute` method can also access this child item via `SelectedParent == null ? null : SelectedParent.SelectedChild;`. Would you mind adding some information regarding what is missing?

Comment: What happens when you perform single left click on lets say `C1`.Is `SelectedParent` fired up ?

Comment: No, the SelectedParent is only changed when the Lists SelectedItem is changed. Do you mean that you require the WindowViewModel to be notified when the Child Selection is changed? I guess the WindowViewModel could hook up to a PropertyChanged on it's children to see when the SelectedChild is changed. Does that sound correct? If so, would you like me to modify the example to include it?

Comment: @kyle I added a smaller example. Check it and get back to me if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass the CurrentItem to the MyCommand as `CommandParameter` right?

Then you only have to:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding CurrentItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? You can set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of your `SelectedItem` to `PropertyChanged`

Comment: I build an example for you later

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListBox,Path=SelectedItem.CurrentItem}"
```